SSH can't connect to my public IP
4928 2024-06-09 19:04:41.088 debug3: checking match for 'Group administrators' user hanul host [publicIP] addr [publicIP] laddr [publicIP] lport 22
4928 2024-06-09 19:04:41.088 debug3: get_passwd: Invalid account type: 3.
4928 2024-06-09 19:04:41.088 debug1: Can't match group at line 88 because user hanul does not exist
4928 2024-06-09 19:04:41.088 debug3: match not found
4928 2024-06-09 19:04:41.089 Invalid user hanul from [publicIP] port 3948

I'm trying to connect to an SSH remote server. I'm using Windows.
I've generated the key, and I've also checked the firewall for port 22.
But when I try to connect, it asks for a password, and when I enter the password for the user account, I get "Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive)"
Why can't I connect?

Pay attention to this text: because user hanul does not exist

@RomeoNinov I see that there is definitely a user named hanul. I don't know why I'm getting that text.

What locale is your system configured to exactly? [Edit] your question instead of submitting a temporary comment. Submit your entire OpenSSH configuration file. Post a screenshot of the lists of users on the target machine showing that the user in question actually exists. Additionally we need the ACL for the key in question showing the user your trying to use is the only user with access to the key. Without this information, and there might be more information required, your question cannot be answered

Your remote server is using windows ssh group config. So the server side config is denying you entry.
you mentioned you generated a key but made no mention of placing the authorized key on the remote server.
without further info it sounds like you are attempting to connect to a remote server that is not aware of your ssh credentials, as a user that does not exist on the server.
Ensure user Hanul exists on the remote server
Ensure Hanul is in the group 'Group Administrators' on the remote server.
Ensure your SSH public key is in the authorized keys file on the remote server.
Reattempt your connection it should work
